# SharePoint server domain joined or not

Tags: 2013, adfs, cross-domain

In case I want to set up authentication with two domains.

I would install 2 ADFS server (1 on each domain), configure SharePoint to enable authentication.

But, does my sharepoint server needs to be domain-joined ? If yes, to which one ?

My two domains will be for internal users (already existing) and external customers (the one I'm gonna create).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add the SP servers to domain of external customers AD. You can configure ADFS to use claims between SP and the external customers AD.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446526.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer, according to what you said here, the SP Server could be joined to internal domain ? and both internal/external users will be able to connect to SharePoint as long as I have 2 ADFS Servers in my two domains

Comment: You will add SP servers to internal domain and configure ADFS for external domain.

Comment: Thanksyou really much for answering me @Luccio ! So, to describe in one word : SP Servers in internal Domain + ADFS in External Domain is enough to allow external users to loggin in SP Site ? Or should I add ADFS in internal domain too ? I must admit, that I don't really understand 100% what are ADFS Roles (except landing on authentication page that gives you a token that is passed to an application)

Comment: IMHO you will need 2 ADFS and exchange certificates to trust each other. See saml-token base authentication: http://zoom.it/pPoz#full also please check this article where is the configuration of both adfs explained http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=109

Comment: Ok, I've already bookmarked this link from helloitsliam. But now, with your help, I'm able to understand it better ! Thank you ! If you can confirm me a last thing : adfs servers must me domain joined ... right ? May be a idiot question, but can find any info on this. And the real last question : any advices about implementing this between DMZ and LAN ? I mean : internal AD/ADFS located in LAN, and both external AD/ADFS/SP server(that hosts portal site) in DMZ ? or should I just let SP/ADFS on DMZ and open ports in firewall ?

Comment: I am afraid I am not able to answer that...maybe there is a better solution than using two AD FS. Maybe you can just have one AD in your domain an combine it somehow with external AD FS. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks though, you helped ! If someone can bring more informations, you're welcome